# Does address of an unordered_map::iterator->first change upon subequent insertions & deletions?

Tags: c++, iterator, unordered-map

Once a key value pair is inserted into an unordered_map and let's say iter is pointing to this pair, would &iter->first be unchanged throughout the lifetime of this pair being present in the unordered_map?

The keys would mostly be long strings, so I'd like to store their iterator->first's addresses at other referring places rather than the strings themselves.

Comment: Hello PreferenceBean, I went through the link you have posted here. I do see the relevant portion " Unsorted associative containers : unordered_[multi]{set,map}: all iterators invalidated when rehashing occurs, but references unaffected [23.2.5/8]." which does answer my question.  Please suggest if any further action is needed from my side w.r.t this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be fine, unless you erase the element directly.

For [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert),

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. **References are not invalidated**. Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is greater than `max_load_factor()*bucket_count()`.

For [`std::unordered_map::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase),

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. **Other iterators and references are not invalidated**.

Comment: Yes, I had known that rehashing causing iterators to get invalidated, but are keys also reallocated? Isn't a new iterator allocated pointing to the same key instance in memory which gets returned again as iterator->first?

Comment: @vrk001 My bad. I misunderstood your question. I've modified my answer.